# When debugging a 3ds Max plugin, 3ds Max always closes when exiting debugging

Tags: c++, sdk, 3dsmax

When I want to debug a plugin from Visual Studio, 3ds Max gets started and takes minutes to load up on my computer. When it's on, everything works fine. But when I stop debugging, 3ds Max closes and it will take anoter few minutes to load 3ds Max up.

Is this normal? If yes, is there a way how to have it staying open? If no, where could the problem lie?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal.
You have to relaunch 3dsmax every time you recompile and debug your plugin.
Since 3dsmax has to load your newly compiled plugin.

It's not a 'problem' - it's how debugging works.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not the truth! You can use Edit&Continue, but only with the x32 version of Max (i.e. up to Max2013) as up to VS1012 MS does not support x64 platforms with this feature. But of course it depends which type of plugin you develop and what you always change in the code. I usually have to launch Max only 2-3 times per day for plugin developments.